# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as mentioned.
[Steam Pressure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XmjH.png)

I want to add a new column after doing simple math.

First I tried:

```
pd.eval("HRSGHPSteam = df1.HRSGHPStmPressure/1000", target=df1)
```

this gives me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'object' and '<class 'int'>'`

then I tried

```
df1['HRSGHPSteam'] = df1['HRSGHPStmPressure']/1000
```

this gives me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'`

Can someone please advise how I can rectify this problem?

Comment: Almost surely because you read in df1 's columns as 'string' or 'object' rather than  float. Edit the question to show us the `pd.read_csv()` or whatever command you used to read in df1. Note that [`pd.read_csv()` has a dtype argument you can use to specify dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), and see the many existing examples of that on SO.

Comment: Also, `df1.info()` will tell you the type of each column.

Comment: You are correct I need to change the read_csv instead of read_excel as the data in excel file is string and numeric both. Example For the cell value 6646 in background formula is {=PISampDat("\\AAA0-I00101M\2000-000:H111.11PI222",'Block 2 '!$B$3,'Block 2 '!$B$4,'Block 2 '!$B$5,0,"")}. Due to that pandas frame may not be able to calculate. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because df1['HRSGHPStmPressure'] is object datatype?
try:

```
df1['HRSGHPStmPressure'] = df1['HRSGHPStmPressure'].astype(int)
```

and then divide by 1000.

Comment: Yes it is object datatype. I tried first                                                                df1['HRSGHPStmPressure'] = df1['HRSGHPStmPressure'].astype(int)                                              but gives me ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Bad Input'

Comment: try df1['HRSGHPStmPressure'] = df1['HRSGHPStmPressure'].astype(float). If not, maybe there is text data in the column

Comment: Yes I noticed data was having combination of string and numeric which was creating error. I need to do clean up. Thanks for your quick help.

Comment: sure, if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting my answer, thanks.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Thanks for your help.